# Shouldn't we close the FileStream instance after finishing using it?

Tags: c#

I saw some examples about using the FileStream from the MSDN, however there is no close() after using it, is it a bug for the MSDN ?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `using` keyword makes sure it will close.

Comment: Those `FileStream`s are part of a `using` block. Once the program leaves that block, then `Dispose` is called on the streams, which involves calling `Close` as well.

Comment: Yeah, I remember it ,it seems I didn't touch c# for a lone time......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any resource (ex: stream), that implements `IDisposable` interface, mostly uses unmanaged resources and should be disposed using  `Dispose`  method.

But -- ***"If your language supports a construct such as the using statement in C# and the Using statement in Visual Basic, you can use it instead of explicitly calling IDisposable.Dispose yourself."***

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx